# OSX El Capitan terminal/.bash_profile color bug

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-elcapitan, github-for-mac

I recently updated to El Capitan and I've been seeing some issues with my terminal, and I narrowed it down to my .bash_profile. I have this in my .bash_profile, so the prompt will change color based on changes in git.

```
# A more colorful prompt
# \[\e[0m\] resets the color to default color
c_reset='\[\e[0m\]'
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
c_path='\[\e[0;31m\]'
# \e[0;32m\ sets the color to green
c_git_clean='\[\e[0;32m\]'
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
c_git_dirty='\[\e[0;31m\]'
```

It was working with the latest update from OSX Yosemite. Also, so far as I can tell, the color codes are correct. However, this is how my terminal appears:

```
github.io [\[\e[0;31m\]working\[\e[0m\]]:>
```

As you can see, I am on my "working" branch of a github directory. Anything that is not on github appears normal.

```
Downloads:>
```

As of right now, I've switched to iTerm which doesn't seem to have the issue for the latest version (which is updated to accomodate El Capitan). Leaving me to think it is a terminal issue rather than github.

[image: Screenshot of Terminal]

Comment: Hardcoding escape sequences guarantees it will only work on certain type of terminal. The right way is to use terminal capabilities which generates the appropriate escape sequences for the type of terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `tput setaf` worked well for me. Documentation [here.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization)

```
# A more colorful prompt
# \[\e[0m\] resets the color to default color
c_reset=$(tput setaf 0)
#  \e[0;31m\ sets the color to purple
c_path=$(tput setaf 55)
# \e[0;32m\ sets the color to green
c_git_clean=$(tput setaf 2)
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
c_git_dirty=$(tput setaf 9)
```

To see all the colors, I ran one of the scripts from that documentation:

```
for C in {0..255}; do
    tput setaf $C
    echo -n "$C "
done
tput sgr0
echo
```

Then whatever colors you want, you know the number to insert after 'tput setaf '

Side note: it looks like we have the same bash_profile source. I also found that upgrading to El Capitan broke it. You can also fix the path color by adding a semicolon in the middle of this line:

```
# PS1 is the variable for the prompt you see everytime you hit enter
PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND'; PS1="${c_path}\W${c_reset}$(git_prompt) :> "'
```

That seems to have fixed my path name color as well. :)

Comment: This is the best answer. `tput` generates the escape sequence appropriate for the type of terminal.

Answer (score 0):

It may be simplest to just set all of these to the default terminal color. That escape sequence appears to be working correctly in your terminal example:

```
# A more colorful prompt
# \[\e[0m\] resets the color to default color
c_reset='\[\e[0m\]'
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
c_path='\[\e[0m\]'
# \e[0;32m\ sets the color to green
c_git_clean='\[\e[0m\]'
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
c_git_dirty='\[\e[0m\]'
```

If that does not work. see if you have access to `tput` and get the needed colors from that. Or finally you can try using ANSI escape sequences

Perhaps try experimenting with ANSI escape sequences in the terminal using `printf`:

```
printf "\033[32m This will appear green on most terminals\n"

printf "\033[31m This will appear red on most terminals\n"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely have to check this out.